# Optimization of nonlinear equation system

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I am quite new to Mathematica and need to solve the following problem:
The problam is dependent on two constants, namely lphi and rmax.

```
lphi = 2 (c + p/e)
p = b^2/a
e = c/a
b = Sqrt[a^2 - ((4*a^2)/(lphi^2))]
thetatangentline = ArcTan[e]
t = Sqrt[p^2 - (p/e)^2]
s = a*(Sin[
     thetacircle] + (thetacircle - 
       Sin[thetacircle])*((b/a)^(2 - 0.216*thetacircle^2)))
f = 2 (t + s)
```

So, now I want to Maximize b

```
rmax = 151.42840717646078443148910480787
NMaximize[{b, lphi == 150, f == rmax, thetacircle < 90°}, 
{lphi, c, p, e, a, thetatangentline, t, s, thetacircle, f}, 
{lphi, c, p, e, a, thetatangentline, t, s, thetacircle, f, b} ∈ Reals]
```

But Mathematica just answers with

```
Hold[NMaximize[{b, lphi == 150, f == rmax, 
   thetacircle < 90 \[Degree]}, {lphi, c, p, e, a, thetatangentline, 
   t, s, thetacircle, 
   f}, {lphi, c, p, e, a, thetatangentline, t, s, thetacircle, f, 
    b} \[Element] Reals]]
```

How can I tell Mathematica to solve this problem?
I read through a bunch of questions, but none seems to address my problem.

I am aware of the fact, that there is a "circle dependency" between the equations, that's why I need mathematica!

Comment: Replace infinite recursions by finite ones

Comment: @Coolwater I would love to, but I have no clue how to tell Mathematica to evaluate the recursion just do a depth, for example, 20 and accept the result...

Comment: As written your code gives errors when it gets to `b`, can you please fix the definitions of `lphi, p, e` and `b` so they aren't circular.

Comment: @KraZug As I have written: I am aware, that there ia circle dependency. That's the problem with the whole problem. It cannot be solved analytical so Mathematica has to optimize/solve numerically. There is no way to resolve this dependency because that would change the problem and all equations must be satisfied.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are trying to do mathematically.

Comment: Long story short:
Calculating an acoustic waveformer.
This paper explains the whole thing:
http://www.excelsior-audio.com/Publications/Hughes_-_Progressive_Degenerate_Ellipsoidal_Phase_Plug_(AES139,_2015-10).pdf

Comment: @java4ever The link in your comment produces a URL Not Found error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing your equations as a set of equations, rather than assignments:

```
eqns = Simplify[{lphi == 2 (c + p/e), p == b^2/a, e == c/a, 
   b == Sqrt[a^2 - ((4*a^2)/(lphi^2))], ttl == ArcTan[e], 
   t == Sqrt[p^2 - (p/e)^2], f == 2 (t + s), 
   s == a*(Sin[tc] + (tc - Sin[tc])*((b/a)^(2 - 0.216*tc^2)))}]
```

(where I've used `tc` and `ttl` instead of `thetacircle` and `thetatangentline`, you could also use greek letters in the variable names). You have eight equations in eleven unknowns. Two of which are `f` and `lphi`, which are parameters that you are giving.

You can now solve these first seven equations, to express them all in terms of `e` (other variables may be able to be used, particularly if you remove the `ttl` eqn which doesn't do anything here.)

```
sub = Solve[eqns[[1;;7]], {a, b, c, p, s, t, ttl}][[1]]
```

You can then use `NMaximize` to solve maximize the value of b, given the remaining equation connecting `e` and `tc`

```
Maximize[{b, eqns[[7]], tc <= \[Pi]/2} /. sub /. lphi -> 150 /. 
  f -> 151, {e, tc}]
(* {37.0431, {e -> 1.16977, tc -> 1.5193}} *)
```

Which I think is the kind of answer that you want. 
For some reason that I don't understand but is presumably an artefact of the maximisation routine, adding the restriction $\theta_c>0$ gives me a worse answer, even though the earlier one is still valid. That may be worthy of a new question, or someone who knows more details on Maximize can chip in.

```
Maximize[{b, eqns[[7]], 0 <= tc <= \[Pi]/2} /. sub /. lphi -> 150 /. 
  f -> 151, {e, tc}]
(* {34.852, {e -> 1.473, tc -> 1.43206}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this later. The equations from the paper are wrong, I developed a new set.